# How do I add an image to a list in Pug

Tags: node.js, pug

Can't find an answer to this anywhere. I have a simple list in pug, and I thought I was supposed to use the syntax I have below. The image placeholder shows up and the styling (size) in the rendered website, but there is a 404 on the image in my Visual Studio console. I thought the image needed to be in the same folder as the `index.pug` file, which it is. Any ideas why it won't show up?

```
extends layout

block content
  doctype html
  html(lang="en")
    head
      meta(charset='utf-8')
      meta(name='viewport' content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1')
    section
      nav
        ul
          li.title Study Bot
          li.robot 
            img(src='robot-face.jpg' alt='Robot face' width='130px')
      article
    footer
      iframe#encyclopedia-window(src='https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/')
```

Comment: Does `src='./robot-face.jpg` work?

Comment: Unfortunately not, but the static thing in the answer worked!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Images are static content. So we have to specify the directory for static assets.
So create a folder named public (or anything you like), place the image file in it.

Then in index.js(or your entry point):

```
app.use(express.static('public'))
```

Now path to image becomes:

```
src='/static/robot-face.jpg'
```

More in the documentation [Serving static files in Express](https://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html)

Comment: Thank you! I did not know about the static thing, I'm new to Pug. I had to tweak my code a little, but I noticed there was already this: `app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));` in my `app.js` file. So I put the image in the public/images folder and changed my `index.pug` file `img` tag to this: `img(src='/images/robot-face.jpg' alt='Robot face' width='130px')`, and that fixed it!

Comment: @Azuresport glad it worked! these little things are easy to miss. Can you please mark this as answer :)

Comment: sorry about that! I thought I had marked as the answer, but then it did not take. It's marked now. :)

Comment: Hey Azurespot, upvoting an answer is not the same as accepting an answer. Can you also accept @SanSolo's answer if it solved your issue?